# What is the URL for the Visual Studio 2017 downloads?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio on one of our build servers but I need to add an exception on the firewall for the install because internet access is disabled on our servers, and unfortunately enabled full internet access is prohibited. I can download the initial 1MB installer, but when the installer initiates it tries to download addition files and this is where the breakdown is happening.

I have added an exception for *.microsoft.com but this doesn't seem to have worked. Does anyone know what the URL for the download is where it tries to retrieve the additional installer files?

Comment: You can find a domain list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should rather consider an offline installation process. See here for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio

Comment: Yeah, except he asks for vs 2018 - which is not there.

Answer (score -1):

The 2017 version, will be followed by a 2019 version, and the download for the 2017 version is extremely public at....

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

Comment: He is asking for the connections used by the installer, not for the download website.